# SEGV_ACCERR after room creation Google Play game services

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, google-play-games

I'm writing the game with Cocos2d-x and Google Play Game Services for the networking.
I'm creating a real time room with this code:

```
 auto scene = BattleScene::createScene();
    BattleScene *layer;
    if (scene->getChildByName("layer")) {
      layer = static_cast<BattleScene *>(scene->getChildByName("layer"));
    } else {
      log("Cannot get layer!");
      return;
    }
    log("Creating room...");
    auto gameServices = StateManager::getGameServices();
    gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig config = gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig::Builder()
                                         .SetMinimumAutomatchingPlayers(1)
                                         .SetMaximumAutomatchingPlayers(1)
                                         .Create();
    log("config created");
    gameServices->RealTimeMultiplayer().CreateRealTimeRoom(
        config, layer,
        [&](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse const
                &response) {
          log("created a room %d", response.status);
          if (gpg::IsSuccess(response.status)) {
            gameServices->RealTimeMultiplayer().ShowWaitingRoomUI(
                response.room, 1,
                [&](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::
                        WaitingRoomUIResponse const &wait_response) {
                  log("WaitingRoomUIResponse");
                  if (IsSuccess(wait_response.status)) {
                    log("Game started");
                    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
                  }
                });
          } else
            log("Error1");
        });
```

But then (when second player connected) application fails with that log:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 00584918
Stack frame #00  pc 00584918  [heap]
Stack frame #01  pc 004d4526  /data/data/com.railon.luck/lib/libMyGame.so: Routine std::_Function_handler<void (gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&), gpg::RealTimeEventListenerHelperImpl::RealTimeEventListenerHelperImpl(gpg::IRealTimeEventListener*)::{lambda(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&)#5}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&) at libgcc2.c:?
Stack frame #02  pc 004ec9c8  /data/data/com.railon.luck/lib/libMyGame.so (_ZNKSt8functionIFvRKN3gpg12RealTimeRoomERKNS0_22MultiplayerParticipantEEEclES3_S6_): Routine std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&)>::operator()(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&) const at ??:?
Stack frame #03  pc 004eca08  /data/data/com.railon.luck/lib/libMyGame.so: Routine std::_Function_handler<void (), gpg::RealTimeEventListenerHelperImpl::WrappedRealTimeEventListener::OnParticipantStatusChanged(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&)::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) at libgcc2.c:?
Stack frame #04  pc 00509f6a  /data/data/com.railon.luck/lib/libMyGame.so: Routine gpg::PlatformExecuteOperation(std::function<void ()> const&) at libgcc2.c:?
```

The problem seems to be in `OnParticipantStatusChanged` func in `BattleSceneClass`, but there is a error even when this func is empty
Do you have some ideas?
Yes, `BattleScene` have `IRealTimeEventListener` in parents.

Comment: If you use `ndk-stack` and pass it a file with the entire trace, starting with `***` you might get an improved traceback.

Comment: @TankorSmash unfortunately, it's output of ndk-stack (I passed logcat result in it)

Comment: Oh bummer, I usually get file paths.

Comment: @TankorSmash in other cases I had full file paths

Comment: Could the scene be destroyed? What is the scope of the auto scene variable?  Does it behave differently if you don't declare it but static?  Is there other ways the layer object can be destroyed so the address of the callback becomes invalid?